# Choosing where to start

Tags: order-and-chaos-online

I have just started playing Order and Chaos 2 and have enjoyed by first account playing, but I decided to make an alt account I know  what class and race I want to be but now I have decided I want to start in cliffside instead of mariners landing. I have heard this is possible from other forums but I don't know how... Does anyone else know how? I would be very grateful as I cannot find anything on other forums or wikis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from [a video](https://youtu.be/XMwloMfTqeo?t=3m42s) from October 2015, you should be able to select your starter vilage as part of character creation. It is possible that for a first time player, you're limited to one of them.

Comment: So what are u saying I can't start in a different area I'm already lvl 27 on my main account